# What happens if there are no parameters after format using printf?

Tags: c, stack, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Behaviour of printf when printing a %d without supplying variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437816/behaviour-of-printf-when-printing-a-d-without-supplying-variable-name)

What happens if I use, for example, printf("%d %d"); ?
Will it just pop the last eight bytes from the stack and print them out?

Answer (score 1):

In GCC - you get a warning (this is done using `__attribute__ ((__warn_unused_result__))`).

On x86 you don't get a stack error, as the caller will push the data to the stack, and also pop after the function returned. This is called the C calling convention, unlike pascal - in which the function will also pop the data from the stack (using `ret 10` in ASM for example).

The values of the data you required will be random.

Answer (score 0):

Technically its undefined behaviour if the number of format specifiers in `printf()` is greater than the number of arguments.

However the following is fine

```
printf("%d",x,y); // y is evaluated but not printed.
```

---

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you'll get `garbage data` which relies upon the compiler and its compiling option....

Answer (score 0):

It will print garbage values but it has 'More % conversions than data arguments' warning.