# What address am I printing out?

Tags: c, security, stack, buffer-overflow

In this example C program,

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("%p\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am confused as to what exactly I'm printing.  The address it prints changes every time I run the program, so I assume the address has something to do with the stack, like maybe where it starts or something, but I am not sure.

EDIT: The above program comes from a more elaborate example of a simple buffer overflow attack from "Writing Secure Code" (2nd edition) by Michael Howard and David LeBlanc (2003).  In the foo method, the first printf says "My stack looks like: \n%p... etc. so I was wondering how that was possible because there's no argument passed to the printf function, but I asked here because maybe there was something I was missing.  My apologies for not including it in the original post.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo (const char* input)
{   
    char buf[10];

    printf("My stack looks like:\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n\n");
    strcpy(buf, input);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    printf("Now the stack looks like:\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n\n");
}

void bar (void) 
{ 
    printf("Augh! I've been hacked!\n"); 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Address of foo = %p\n", foo);
    printf("Address of bar = %p\n", bar);
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Please supply a string as an argument!\n");
                return -1;
    } 

    foo (argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker because the OP doesn't realize that it's wrong code. That's why he/she is asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have covered that this is undefined behavior.  You cannot make any
guarantees about code that invokes undefined behavior.  So the code you have
posted likely *does not work* except for a very specific implementation (e.g.,
gcc 4.3 on x86 with no extra compiler flags or optimizations, let's say).

But let's have fun and guess how the code was intended to work on a specific
platform with a specific compiler with specific flags at a specific optimization
level.

The main idea that will help you here is that the compiler must generate some
code to give a function its arguments, and the function must have some code
to be able to access those arguments.  And then someone, either the caller or
the function, must have code to clean up the arguments so that memory (if used
at all) is not leaked.

But here's the rub:  the compiler generating code to call the function may not
be the same as the compiler that compiled the function.

So the platform architects and compiler writers and various other stakeholders
got together and came up with some [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).  The calling
convention is part of the platform's [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), and as long as every compiler
implements to the same ABI, then their compiled libraries will be compatible.

Because of the ABI, I can implement a function using my compiler and give you
the generated object file.  You can write code to call this function, and link
with my object file (library).  If our compilers both generate code that adheres
to the proper calling conventions and ABI, then it will all work out.

As you can guess, the calling convention for every platform is different.  The
[calling convention on x86 processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) for variadic functions like `printf`
is called the *cdecl* calling convention.  In this calling convention, the
caller pushes all arguments onto the stack (in reverse order) and once the
function is done, the caller pops the arguments off the stack.

So what you're seeing is that you've called `printf` and provided 1 argument,
which is your format string.  This is what happens (for cdecl):

1. Your code pushes a pointer to the format string onto the stack and calls
   the function `printf`.
2. `printf` reads the format string, which is on the top of the stack.
3. `printf` sees `%p` in the format string.  You have told it that there is
   another argument on the stack, this argument is a pointer, and that `printf`
   should print the value of this pointer.
4. But there is no other argument on the stack.  `printf` interprets whatever
   arbitrary garbage is on the stack as a pointer and prints it.

And so the more `%p`'s you give it, the more stack data it will print.

What garbage it prints is (you guessed it) undefined.  You'll have to study your
platform and compiler to know and understand what's there.

Answer (score 4):

The program has undefined behaviour because there is no argument for format specifier `%p` in function call

```
printf("%p\n");
```

From the C Standard

Description

> 2 The fprintf function writes output to the stream pointed to by
>   stream, under control of the string pointed to by format that
>   specifies how subsequent arguments are converted for output. **If
>   there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

The same is valid for function `printf`

Comment: Note that even if a valid pointer was supplied to the `printf` function, the address could still be different every time the program is executed (or maybe compiled... it's been a while since I've thought about C)

Comment: I edited my original post, hopefully that adds more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You have some [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (as [answered by Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26617759/841108)). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108). Explaining the actual printed value is trying to understand that undefined behavior, and this requires understanding specific implementation details (what [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), what exact machine code was generated -it depends upon the compiler, the system, the processor...-, what was the machine state at beginning of `main`, etc...).

A possible reason of why the printed address is different at every run is [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). Probably the compiler is passing some address on the stack, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18459172/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26464254/841108). I guess that the runtime behavior would also vary if you pass several different arguments to your `main` or if you change your environment (on Linux, with `bash`, with `export SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=something-useless-but-long` before running your program)

Comment: I edited my original post, hopefully that adds more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` relies on the format string to tell it how many and what types of additional arguments to expect.  When you pass `%p` in the format string, `printf` expects there to be an additional argument of type `void *`, and it wlil try to read a value from wherever it expects that additional argument to be (whether on the stack or in a register).  Whether or not this is exploitable from a malware perspective depends on the calling convention for that platform.

If you pass too few arguments or arguments of the wrong type for the given conversion specifier, you can get anything from garbage output to a segfault.  The language standard leaves the behavior *undefined*, meaning the compiler isn't required to issue a warning or to handle the problem in any particular way.